# Codeception doesn't show functions in terminal

Tags: php, terminal, codeception

I'm using Codeception 2.2.1 in my machine and in a remote machine in the same net (which I access through the same terminal).

Codeception config is a exact copy in both, but when I run tests in my machine it doesn't show the functions:

[image: Wrong terminal example]

but when I access the remote machine (through the same terminal) it shows correctly:

[image: Correct terminal example]

What can cause that and how to solve?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is far from ideal, but I solved it writing this line at the beginning of each of my functions:

```
echo "\033[0;36m".__METHOD__."\033[0m\n";
```

Wich prints current "Class::functionName", colored in cyan.

Comment: The issue was also solved after updating Codeception to a newer version `sudo php codecept.phar self-update`